# Puppeteer Script Works Local But Not On EC2 AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

I am running the following script on EC2 AWS with Amazon Linux AMI

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

url_ =  'https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/ES*0/interactive-chart/fullscreen';

func()

async function func() {
    console.log(0)
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    console.log(1)
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log(2)
    await page.goto(url_);
    console.log(page)

    return page
}
```

since today, with no changes on or new installs on EC2, the script stopped working while it was working until yesterday.

The same script on Local Machine still works.

Instead on EC2 gives the following error:

> (node:12636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
>       at CDPSession.LifecycleWatcher._eventListeners.helper.addEventListener (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:47:107)
>       at CDPSession.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at CDPSession._onClosed (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:215:10)
>       at Connection._onClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:138:15)
>       at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener.event (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:45:22)
>       at WebSocket.onClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
>       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at WebSocket.emitClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:191:10)
>       at Socket.socketOnClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:850:15)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>     -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
>       at Page.goto (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:656:49)
>       at Page. (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
>       at func (/home/ec2-user/hd/scrape_bk.js:19:13)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:12636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:12636) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

if I give instead this URL (http://www.google.com) I get this error on EC2 (while it still works on local machine):

> (node:12938) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Page crashed!
>       at Page._onTargetCrashed (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:185:24)
>       at CDPSession.Page.client.on.event (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:140:56)
>       at CDPSession.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at CDPSession._onMessage (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:200:12)
>       at Connection._onMessage (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:112:17)
>       at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener.event (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:41:24)
>       at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
>       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
>       at Receiver.emit (events.js:189:13)
>   (node:12938) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:12938) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>   (node:12938) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
>       at CDPSession.LifecycleWatcher._eventListeners.helper.addEventListener (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:47:107)
>       at CDPSession.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at CDPSession._onClosed (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:215:10)
>       at Connection._onClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:138:15)
>       at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener.event (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:45:22)
>       at WebSocket.onClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
>       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at WebSocket.emitClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:191:10)
>       at Socket.socketOnClose (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:850:15)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>     -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
>       at Page.goto (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:656:49)
>       at Page. (/home/ec2-user/hd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
>       at func (/home/ec2-user/hd/scrape_bk.js:13:13)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:12938) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

I have no idea how to identify the source of the problem since it came out suddenly with no changes to machine or code and on my local machine it works fine.

Comment: Have you checked the [Troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)? Is the machine maybe limited due to memory/CPU?

Comment: is it possible that the errors are due to a lack of disk space? I have only 100MB left

Comment: Yes, quite possible. I'm pretty sure that memory/CPU/disk/network problems can lead to browser crashes.

Comment: I guess that's teh solution then, makes sense

Comment: Glad I could help. I hope it's okay I added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems puppeteer is able to start the browser but it then randomly crashes. This should not be happening on a normal machine and might be happening due to resource constraints.

You should check if your system is running correctly. In particular, you might want to check:

- Memory usage
- CPU usage
- Disk usage

Too few memory or not enough CPU power might lead to random crashes as well as not enough hard disk space.